# Applying background on scrollview

Tags: android

this is the activity im trying to put a background on ! 
the thing is when i remove the Relativelayout and leave the scroll view and the linear it work fine !

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background">
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="56dp"
        android:paddingLeft="24dp"
        android:paddingRight="24dp"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <ImageView android:src="@drawable/logo"
            android:layout_width="3023dp"
            android:layout_height="129dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1.06" />

        <!-- Name Label -->
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editTextUserName"
                android:hint="User Name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textCapWords"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <!--  Email Label -->
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">
            <EditText android:id="@+id/input_email"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:hint="Email"
                android:textColorHint="@color/black"
                android:textColor="@color/black"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <!-- Password Label -->
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">
            <EditText android:id="@+id/input_password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:hint="Password"
                android:textColor="@color/black"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/FirstName"
                android:hint="FirstName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/SecondName"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Middle Name"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/LastName"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Family Name"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/Birthday"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="MM/YYYY"
                android:inputType="date"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/PhoneNumber"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Phone Number"
                android:inputType="phone"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/Address"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Area"
                android:inputType="text"
                />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


        <!-- Signup Button -->
        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_signup"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:text="Create Account"/>

        <TextView android:id="@+id/link_login"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:text="Already a member? Login"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="16dip"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

these are the erorrs shown up when i try to acsess it from signin activity

```
03-21 12:14:37.355  14501-14501/com.sourcey.materialloginexample E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.sourcey.materialloginexample, PID: 14501
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sourcey.materialloginexample/com.sourcey.materiallogindemo.SignupActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #3: Error inflating class <unknown>
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #3: Error inflating class <unknown>
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
            at com.sourcey.materiallogindemo.SignupActivity.onCreate(SignupActivity.java:28)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
            at com.sourcey.materiallogindemo.SignupActivity.onCreate(SignupActivity.java:28)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:594)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:429)
            at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:840)
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2110)
            at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
            at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3554)
            at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3484)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:464)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:236)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
            at com.sourcey.materiallogindemo.SignupActivity.onCreate(SignupActivity.java:28)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the size of your background image, you are running out of memory when It's building the RelativeLayout:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:594)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:429)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:840)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2110)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3554)
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3484)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:464)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:236)
```

You should use mipmap folders and resize your background for each kind of device resolution not to consume a lot of memory when It's creating the view.